# "Bullet-proof" logs uploading from NLog, with persistent buffer

Tags: nlog, azure-table-storage

I'm thinking on how to accomplish following logging system, using only nlog with minimum custom code:

- Final destination for logs should be Azure Storage Tables. There is a
  ready target for that.
- But PC may not be connected to internet all
  the time. When it's not - logs should still be saved somewhere else.
  So there should be temporary buffer somewhere whcih persists even
  when app is not running.
- And there should be a task, which uploads
  missed logs when PC is online.

Is it possible to do using only nlog configuration and without custom target? It's ok to add code on Azure side, which will parse uploaded logs data and write them to Storage Tables if needed.
I've considered using MSMQ as a single target and run task which will process uploading from queue. But it forces me to install MSMQ with on every PC. Any other queue storage which can be used in app may be exists?

In addition:

Hiding or encrypting log files on PC is not required. After successfull upload they should be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen anything for NLog that provides automatic durability. But it would be a really nice feature if one could add a durability-targe-wrapper, that saved the output locally to a storage-provider (file / localdb / litedb / sqllite etc.). And allowed background writing to actual target when network was online.

There is only the [RetryingWrapper](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/RetryingWrapper-target) that comes close to the idea, but it fails to handle application restarts.

Alternative then one needs to write to a target that has builtin offline mode like the [Nlog.RabbitMQ.Target](https://github.com/snakefoot/Nlog.RabbitMQ) or [NLog.Mongo](https://github.com/loresoft/NLog.Mongo) (MongoDb Realm).

Yet another alternative is to write to a simple file in a structured format (Json / Gelf / Log4jXml / Csv). And then have a background service uploading the contents when network online. Ex. like LogStash or FileBeat.

K8 cluster-node applications uses console-output (Ex. in Json-Format), and then the cluster-host-application captures this output. The cluster-host-application can then redirect the output to stable storage. This allows the cluster-host-application to shutdown K8 cluster-node without having worry about lost output, because it has already been captured.

Comment: I'm coming to conclusion that such target is a bit out of "target logic". Target should only write logs somewhere, it's not its job to preserve them between sessions. Also some issues rises: with logs we should save their layout, because it can be changed. CSV layout helps here.

Comment: So what is my soultion now - writing text logs files every minute, date and time (up to minutes) is in filename. In log files I only save seconds part. Separate task in my app priodically reading logs dir, trying to upload parsed data to azure and deleting them if succeeded. Last file sorted by date is excluded - it can be current file now and still in use by nlog. Next step - switch to CSV layout with header in every file, so changing fields format or order won't be a problem

Comment: @WolfrevokCats Yes that is also a good approach (have updated my answer). This is also used for elastic-search and graylog, where background-service is used to upload from file to online-service (when available).